# Programmatically retrieve list of supported WiFi frequencies/channels

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant, iw

I'm currently building an application that leverages NetworkManager for providing network configuration functionalities. The application uses the DBus API to communicate with NetworkManager.

I'm now stuck on the following problem: I want to have a UI element that lists the WiFi channels/frequencies that the user can select when setting up a WiFi access point but I'm not able to find a way to ask NetworkManager for this information. If I understand correctly the supported channel/frequencies depend on the network card capabilities and the country code set for the system.

When I use `nmtui` the channel selector is a text box and when I select an unsupported channel it throws an error. It looks like this information is available somewhere but I can't access it.

I know that I can retrieve this info from `iwlist` but, as per their documentation, that command output is not meant to be parsed and is not stable.

I tried skimming through the `wpa_supplicant` DBus API but it doesn't seem to provide this information either.

Is there a service/API I can use for retrieving this information?

Comment: I don't think NM has access to that information. Have a look at [`getChannelInfo`](https://github.com/llazzaro/python3-wifi/blob/master/pythonwifi/iwlibs.py#L256) from `python-wifi`  (which hasn't been maintained for quite some years...)

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks for the feedback. Apparently `python-wifi` uses `iwlib` under the hood, which essentially means using `iwlist`.

I didn't know about `iwlib` and can be interesting using it but the effort is high.

Comment: Well, afaik it's either `iwlib` (python, haskell etc) or parsing the `iw` output (which is still considered work in progress...)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [LinSSID](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linssid/) which will provide you the list of SSIDs and channel they use.

Comment: I don't think that's what op asks for - they want a list of locally legal and technically possible wifi channels, not a list of available networks.

Comment: Yup, I'm trying to find the channels that a WiFi device supports not the APs seen by the device. The equivalent of `iwlist channel` but from a service providing a stable API since, as per `iw` documentation, you should "_NOT screenscrape this tool, we don't consider its output stable_"